# Hiding site actions menu in moss depending on page

Tags: sharepoint, menu, conditional-statements

I am trying to hide the site actions menu from certain pages with our moss enviroment, specifically non-publishing pages.

I was looking to use the SPSecurityTrimmedControl to achieve it, so in my masterpage I have:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ApproveItems">
<PublishingSiteAction:SiteActionMenu runat="server"/>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

but it seems that this is role based only and not page based. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty way is to build your own wrapper control that hides its child controls based on some criteria that you specify. Exactly like the SPSecurityTrimmedControl!

See [Waldeks blog entry](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/creating-your-own-wrapper-controls-in-sharepoint-2007/). He is hiding the Action menu for anonymous users so you would only have to put in your own criterium.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this or not... but I've had to something similar (hiding/displaying stuff). I created a UserControl and then included it in the masterpage.

**1. Write the code behind your user control**

```
namespace YourCompany.Namespace
{
    public class HideSiteActionsClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected override void  OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            // do work to hide site actions depending on page
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Create your usercontrol ascx file**

Contents of C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\YourUserControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="YourCompany.Namespace.HideSiteActionsClass,YourDLLThatHasTheClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4145551be317a94" compilationMode="Always" %>
```

**3. Add your usercontrol to the masterpage**

Put this at the top:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="yourTagPrefix" TagName="YourTagName" src="~/_controltemplates/YourUserControl.ascx" %>
```

Put this somewhere on the page:

```
<yourTagPrefix:YourTagName id="AUserControlID" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></yourTagPrefix:YourTagName>
```

You can find info on google or [this page](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/11/18/introduction-to-sharepoint-development-deploy-a-user-control-in-sharepoint.aspx).